# seeing error in pom.xml and build as well failing

Tags: maven, selenium

I am trying to create a Maven project for a automation project.  I copied selenium, testng, and other depedencies.  Iam seeing below error in my pom file.

Failure to transfer org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:pom:2.22.0 from https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2 was cached in the 
 local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of central has elapsed or updates are forced. Original error: Could 
 not transfer artifact org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:pom:2.22.0 from/to central (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2): 
 Connection reset

My POM file looks as below:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>com.chevron.app</groupId>
  <artifactId>AEMSitesAutomation</artifactId>
  <packaging>jar</packaging>
  <version>1.0</version>
  <name>AEMSitesAutomation</name>
  <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>
  <build>
  <plugins>
       <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.22.0</version>
        <configuration>
          <suiteXmlFiles>
            <suiteXmlFile>testng.xml</suiteXmlFile>
          </suiteXmlFiles>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
</plugins>
  </build>
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <version>3.8.1</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
        <dependency>
        <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
        <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
        <version>3.13.0</version>
    </dependency>    

    <dependency>
  <groupId>org.testng</groupId>
  <artifactId>testng</artifactId>
  <version>6.8</version>
  <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
</project>
```

Comment: You have a network issue..  firewall/proxy... furthermore in your project make a decision to use either TestNG or JUnit but not both....

Comment: Thank you.. I tried from other wifi network and it worked fine. I will remove JUnit stuff..